# VBA Number (11-01) as text/number in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I created VBA excel script to get data from website.

When it captures `11-01`, excel automatically converts to 11-Jan (11/01/2012) instead of the original 11-01.

What is the method not to convert the 11-01 to 11-Jan?

```
Address         Unit   Postal
JALAN LEMPHENG  11-01  128791
```

Thanks.

```
Set clip = New DataObject
clip.SetText "<html><table><tr>" _
& "<td>" & ieSearchGet.outerHTML & "</td>" _
& "</tr></table></html>"
clip.PutInClipboard
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
```

Comment: Why are you pasting HTML into the cell?

Comment: Cause I need to get the html table data to paste to the cells

Answer (score 2):

I think the best is to just change the format of the cell you want to paste your data in, before doing so. Does the following work ?

```
Set clip = New DataObject
                clip.SetText "<html><table><tr>" _
                & "<td>" & ieSearchGet.outerHTML & "</td>" _
                & "</tr></table></html>"
                clip.PutInClipboard
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                    Selection.NumberFormat = "@" 'Format as Text the selected cell
                Loop
                ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
```

Comment: it will still show as 11-Jan. 11-01 is actually a unit number extracted from a website

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the character "'" (that is, a single quote) before the text you paste.

I have never tried to do this, so this will probably not be quite the right code.  You will probably have to experiment.  But it's a start:

```
clip.SetText "<html><table><tr>" _
    & "<td>'" & ieSearchGet.outerHTML & "</td>" _
    & "</tr></table></html>"
```

Comment: What is the content of ieSearchGet.outerHTML look like, typically?

Comment: Address         Unit   Postal
JALAN LEMPHENG  11-01  128791

Comment: I understand that, but what I meant was that it's presumably HTML.  What does the HTML look like?  Is it a table?  Does it contain one cell, or multiples?  Etc.  Thank you.

Comment: It is a table and it contains multiple cells. Thanks.